# Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly stopped reading files from CF cards

Tags: sd-card

Thanks in advance
My computer still recognizes the cards, I can open them but there are no files.  This is across multiple cards, and after multiple formatting attempts.  Other computers and cameras can read the files. My computer can (laboriously) recover the files of the card.  But it cannot just open them.  It used to work just fine, not sure what changed.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like your card reader has become faulty. It happens.

Comment: The card reader works on other computers

Comment: The we have insufficient information to help you troubleshoot yet, sorry, Has anybody else reported problems with your model of card reader? Have you looked in /var/log/apt to see what software changed and when? Have you tried your card reader with a 19.10 LiveUSB? What does the kernel report when you plug in the card reader? What does syslog report when you plug a card into the reader? Are you using some special format on the cards? All those and more should be answered in your question above (NOT in comments below).